# MYSQL group by with dynamic where

Tags: mysql

I have table where wind speed is inserted every couple of minutes. Lets say i would then like to calculate average wind speed for certain time window for each day.

I could use SQL command like

```
select ROUND(avg(data.wind),1) wind  
FROM data 
WHERE station in(109) 
&&  hour(data.datum)>=7 
&& hour(data.datum)<= 8 
group by month(data.datum), day(data.datum)
```

This works fine but the problem is i would like to use dynamic time slot based on sunrise time. I found SQL function to calculate sunrise time for a specific date but i dont know how to use dynamic time window for each day in group by in my sample.
For sunrise i would use https://github.com/curzon01/mysql_SunRiseSet
which uses command like

```
select SunRiseSet(yyyy-mm-dd, 45.299, 13.571, 'nautical', 'rise');
```

For example i would like range from sunrise - 1 hour upto sunrise + 1 hour. This would mean

```
day1 7:20-8:20
day2 7:21-8:21
day3 7:23-8:23
etc.
```

Is this possible in one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(data.wind), 1) AS wind  
FROM data 
WHERE station IN (109) 
AND TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(data.datum), SunRiseSet(data.datum, ...))) 
  BETWEEN -3600 AND 3600 
GROUP BY MONTH(data.datum), DAY(data.datum);
```

I assume you can get the coordinates of the respective station to put in where I have left `...`. Maybe join to another table where you store the station details like location?